# Was ist "Fotzenhobel" und woher kommt es?

Tags: etymology, dialect, archaism

Das Wort wird fielfach als "Mundharmonika" gedeutet.

An Dialektwörterbüchern weisen so weit ich sehen kann nur Südhessisches Wörterbuch und Pfälzisches Wörterbuch einen Eintrag für *Fotz-Hobel* auf während Bayerns Dialekte Online auf Belege für *Fotzenhobel* in einer Arbeitsdatenbank verweist. Bayerisches Wörterbuch kennt es scheinbar nicht. (woerterbuchnetz.de)

Das verwundert zuerst, da *Fotzen* im Bezug auf den Mund nunmal bayerisch zu sein scheint insb. im Sinne einer Backpfeife. Stattdessen verweist die Suche auf *Pfotsche, -n*, quasi Pfoten, Füße, etc., was zufällig zu dem Thema gehört, das ich eigentlich gesucht habe:

- altsächsisch *fotskamel* wie althochdeutsch *fuozskamal*, vgl. *Fuß* und *Schemel*; in Runen einmal auch mit *ks*; wohl aus lateinisch *scamnum*, weiteres ungewiss, vielleicht mit *schaben* verwandt, das doch an *hobeln* erinnert.

Übrigens bezeichnet *pfotsch* ferner die Steckrübe.

Woher die Bedeutung *Mund* kommen soll, ist aufs Erste nicht erkennbar.

Zum Hobel: Soweit Pfeifers Etymologie auf *Hof* und irgendwie was dickes verweist, ist das insgesamt entäuschend. Laut Etymologisches Wörterbuch des Althochdeutschen (Band IV, 2008) hat das Wort außerhalb des niederdeutschen keine genaue Entsprechung. Immerhin könnte mit lautmalerei auch Anschluss an *Hupe* gesucht werden, letztendlich nicht stichhaltig. Pfälzisches Wörterbuch bestätigt Pfeifer insoweit mit *Hobel²* bzw. *Hübel, Hubel* als "Hügel", "erhobener Teil eines Dorfes" etc. fast homophon zu *Hobel¹* ist. Zudem verweist eine Redensart auf das entsprechende Verb: *Du kannsch mer de H.* [*huwwel* o.ä.] *ausblose* 'Laß mich in Ruhe!' Entsprechend der Steckrübe (s.o.) gilt das Verb *hobeln* zu 2. *'mit dem Krauthobel schnitzeln'*. Süd-Hessisches Wörterbuch sieht das ähnlich und weiß weiter, s.v. *Hobel* 2. e) “(scherzh.) Mundharmonika, s. *Fotz-, Guschen-, Maul-Hobel.*” nebst anderer Metonyme.

Entsprechend ist dort *Fotze* unter anderem auch als "Mund, Maul" geführt, doch könnte dies ein klassischer Zirkelschluss sein, jedenfalls keine Etymologie. Ebenso denkbar wäre bspw. *Fot* "Spaß, ausgelassene Freude" (nur PfWB) bzw. *fotzeln* "necken". Übrigens kennt BDO sowohl das Schimpfwort als auch "Mund" via Fränkisches Wörterbuch, während BWB es wohl als hochdeutsch begreift und ausschließt.

Weiter habe ich nicht gesucht. Ach doch, eins noch:

Tatsächlich entspricht *Hupe* pfälzisch *Hub, Huben* “aus entrindeten Zweigen geschnittene Pfeife" usw., so Pfeifer, doch hält er dies für lautmalerisch. Vgl. KRS One, “Whoop, whoop, that's the sound of the police”, sowie im Sinne von *Maulfotzen* ebenso allgemein englisch *whoop-ass*.

Nach all dem vorhergesagten ist die Frage doch etwas beschränkt: Was ist "Fotzenhobel" und woher kommt es? Das Ziel, im Ursprung eine gänzlich andere Bedeutung zu finden, die *Hobel* erhellen kann und vielleicht mit Füßen oder wenigstens Holzschuhen zu tun hätte, scheint in keiner Weise gerechtfertigt. Es ist zum heueln.

**Links**

- en.WT “scamnum”: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/scamnum

via https://woerterbuchnetz.de/#0:

- BWB “Pfotsche” etc.: https://publikationen.badw.de/de/bwb/-/2.677.pdf https://publikationen.badw.de/de/bwb/-/2.679.pdf https://publikationen.badw.de/de/bwb/-/2.681.pdf
- SHW “Hobel”: https://www.lagis-hessen.de/de/subjects/rsrec/id/2044/sn/shwb?type=Lemma
- PfWB “Hübel”: https://woerterbuchnetz.de/?sigle=PfWB&lemid=H06815
- EWA “hobil”: https://ewa.saw-leipzig.de/articles/hobil/de#hobil
- Pfeifer “Hobel”: https://www.dwds.de/wb/etymwb/Hobel
- Pfeifer “Hupe”: https://www.dwds.de/wb/etymwb/Hupe

Comment: "die Fotzn" wird in Bayern und Österreich ganz allgemein für "der Mund" verwendet ("Hoit di Fotzn" = sei still). Für die Ohrfeige ist sowohl "die Watsch'n" als auch "die Fotzn" üblich, vielleicht weil man bei Fotzn eher an "auf den Mund schlagen" = "zum Schweigen bringen" denkt. Auch "Fotzenhobel" finde ich geläufig, und es wundert mich, dass das Wort in dem Wörterbuch fehlt.

Answer (score 7):

Man sollte nicht nach einer etymologischen Erklärung von "Hobel" suchen. Die Mundharmonika bewegt sich wie ein Hobel hin- und her. Auf Englisch: That's all.

Comment: Ich hab schon einmal Mundharmonika gespielt, aber nie so heftig, dass mir die Lippen geblutet hätten, wie Gitarristen von ihren Fingern zu berichten wissen. Die übliche Herangehensweise für solche Behauptungen ist der Nachweis von Synonymen, die man dann versuchshalber der Reihe nach als sekundär ausschließen könnte. Dazu fällt mir *Ratsche* ein, zwar ohne Bezug zum Mund soweit mir ersichtlich, aber im Vergleich mit *Rocken* (an anderer Stelle) ist es doch ungefähr genau das, wonach ich gesucht hab. Danke dafür. Die methodische Schwäche dieser Antwort verbietet leider das Häkchen zu setzen.

Comment: Naja, es kommt nicht darauf an, dass du deinen Mund wortwörtlich blutig hobelst wie mit dem echten Holzwerkzeug, sondern einfach dass die gleiche Bewegung ausgeführt wird. Die Bewegung, die der Bewegung beim Hobeln ähnelt, plus die Reibung des Gitters am Mund, führt zu dem Vergleich "wie ein Hobel". Wenn du jemanden eine "Pistensau" schimpfst, dann nicht, weil er exakt wie ein Schwein ist, sondern weil er sich einfach rücksichtslos "wie eine wilde Sau" verhält. Nicht zu viel reininterpretieren, diese Antwort ist die Richtige, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

Zuallererst eine Klarstellung: es heißt nicht der "*Fotzen*hobel", sondern der "**Fo(t)z**hobel"!

"Da Foz" (oder "Fotz", eine standardisierte Schreibung bairischer Mundart existiert nicht) wird mit langem "o" gesprochen und ist ein anderes Wort für "Mund" und damit sollte der Ursprung des Wortes - "Mundhobel" - für die Mundharmonika nachvollziehbar sein.
Genauer gesagt, ist es eine Bezeichnung für die *äußere* Mundregion, nicht aber für Mundhöhle oder gar Rachenraum. Entsprechend gibt es zB im Wienerischen stehende Wendungen wie:

> aan Foz mochn

was "einen Flunsch ziehen" bedeutet. Analoga für "Foz" sind "Goschn", "Pappn" oder (ironisch latinisierend) "Pappalatur".

[Hier ist ein Link](https://echtwien.at/de/wiener-sprache/lexikon/F/1527), leider offenbar nur von Muttersprachlern ediert und damit völlig wertlos.

"De Fotzn" (zum Unterschied von "da Foz" feminin) ist tatsächlich eine Ohrfeige, wird aber mit kurzem "o" gesprochen. Auch hierfür [ein irrelevanter Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LNmarn89hjU).

Comment: [Wiktionary](https://de.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/Fotzenhobel) gibt Fotzhobel als Nebenform von Fotzenhobel an und das Hörbeispiel hat ein kurzes o.

Comment: @Olafant: Hier ist noch ein Link: http://www.fim.uni-linz.ac.at/Woerterbuch_oesterr_deut_englisch.htm. Auch da wird "foz" und "fozn" aufgeführt und ich habe in Österreich das Wort "foz" nie anders als mit langem "o" gesprochen gehört.

Comment: Siehe Wikipedia, Oberfränkisch: “ hat sich die mittelhochdeutsche Vokalreihe /eː/ – /øː/ – /oː/ […] im Oberfränkischen hingegen über die gehobenen Vokale /iː/ – /yː/ – /uː/ zur diphthongierten Reihe /iə/ – /yə/ – /uə/.”

Answer (score -6):

Um gleich mal unwichtigsten Teil der Frage zu wuppen, sei zuerst auf engl. *whoop* eingegangen. Mehrere Suchergebnisse deuten auf *a can of whoop-ass*, ohne weitere Begründung; *eine Dose Mitleid*. Zwei einschlägige Seiten widersprechen sich, ob *whoop* eine allein englische Ableitung aus *whip* sei oder mit Verweis auf gotische Evidenz aus altenglisch herzuleiten und vermutlich urgermanisch sei, dementgegen *whip* ein anderes Wort darstellen dürfte.

- Daraus kann man unter der gewagten Annahme einer früheren Nähe beider Sprachzweige zum nordgermanischen und der Rückwirkung des nordischen Lautwandels *o(o)* < *wo* (vgl. *Odin, Wodan*) in Bezugnahme auf die Redensart vermuten, es liege PIE **up* oder so ähnlich zugrunde, da *open (a can of whoop-ass; fire; ...)* nicht nur wahrscheinlich ist, sondern in Anbetracht der gesuchten Verbindung zu *Hof* (vgl. *hobeln*, *Huben*) wegen dessen offener Architektur überzeugt, insb. bereits in der Fragestellung zitiertes "erhobener Teil eines Dorfes".

Eine darauf gerichtete systematische Untersuchung des aspirierten Anlauts existiert meines Wissens nicht. Leider würde das für den Götternamen ungefähr *Hoden* implizieren, bzw. hochdeutsch ca. *Hut*. Das überzeugt umgehend, weil *hugiz* wie in *Hu-bert* eine umgekehrte Entsprechung in *Oger* erfährt.

Den Plosiv erklärt das nicht, der zumindest im Pfälzischen wohl gar keiner ist. Schreibt man *huwwe* nach alter tradition aus mit doppel-u: *huuuuul*. Und legt den insoweit unwahrscheinlichen Lautwandel als Maßstab an: *ool*. Bleibt abzüglich eines Suffixes gar nicht mehr übrig. Ich sag ja immer, mit einzelnen Phonemen zu operieren, wie es bei einigen Affixen der Fall sein mag, ist schon schwierig. Aber ganz ohne wird es wohl nocht gehen. Im Ergebnis scheint Neoplasie im verb *fotzeln* denkbar. Weiteres ungewiss.

Andererseits ist *hub* "Pfeife" gegenüber *huwwel* eben nicht eindeutig und der Plosiv bleibt interessant. Das eben skizzierte Schema kann ohnehin kaum überzeugen, daher erübrigt sich die Rekursion.

PS: dank @Kritiker's Hinweis, der mich an *Ratsche, Schnarre* usw. erinnert, fällt mir die an entsprechenden Stellen angezeigte Nebenbedeutung “Peitsche” (Zitat von Nöten) erst wieder beim Lesen meiner eigenen Frage ein, a pro pos *wip* "Peitsche", *whoop-ass* “Tracht Prügel”. Tatsächlich ist die Konsonantenstruktur von *Peitsche* gegenüber *Fotze*, *Pfotsche* o.ä. vergleichbar. Ausgangpunkt wäre wohl ein slavisches Lehnwort, etwa tschechisch *bič*. Ob dies an *Ratsche* i.S.v. geschwätziges Weib (vgl. *to bitch*, *petzen*) anzuschleißen sei, bleibt ungewiss. S.a. *Tratschmaul* wie *Tröte*.

Comment: Von huwwel zu huawei ist dann auch nur noch ein Katzensprung,

Comment: Es ist schon eine gewisse Kunst dabei, in der Antwort auf die eigene Frage selbige nicht zu beantworten....

Comment: Das geht ganz gut wenn die eigene Antwort genügend Vorarbeit leistet.